# How to access JSP Map in vanilla Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

First of all, I am not sure if this is even possible due to one being server side and other being client side.

Application that I am working on uses Spring MVC 3.1 and there is a `Map` (lets say `validValuesMap` ) of type `Map<String,Long>` defined in Spring method - `referenceData`.

Due to `Map` being defined in `referenceData` method, this `Map` is available in JSP page and I can use JSTL on this `Map` like - `<core:if test="${(validValuesMap ne null)}">` etc.

Can I use this `Map` in plain JavaScript or jQuery too?

I have to basically perform a simple check on `Long` value of this Map if that is being **greater than zero** for a key and that key is available in the JavaScript function as a `var`.

I have to put that check into an `else if (....)` of JavaScript.

Is that possible? or any other way to perform that validation on client side for a button click event?

Comment: Use a JSON serializer.

Answer (score 0):

Convert that object to JSON on server side itself and then store it in javascript variable to manipulate it later on client side .